# Suppress validation not working on Experience Editor

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-editor, validation

I have implemented multiple validations in base template **field items** and suppressed most of the validation in each children template **standard values** using the "**Suppressed validation rules**" field.

It works perfectly in Sitecore Content Editor when I fill in the fields.

Unfortunately in Experience Editor, the suppress validation is not considered and it looks like its validating all the applied validations. I have set the error level to fatal hence I'm not able to save any fields from Experience Editor.

What am I doing wrong, Or is this a bug from Sitecore?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in Sitecore 8.3 update. Sitecore provided a fix regarding the same. It may be added to the upcoming update.

Comment: Can you please include the issue ID Sitecore has for this fix. So future people who find this post will have the ticket number to provide Sitecore.

Comment: @ChrisAuer Sitecore support asked me not to provide the fix in public forums since it was not tested thoroughly. I would recommend to raise a new ticket with sitecore.